# display flash message with django formview

Tags: django

I have a Django Form that logs when it encounters and error. I would like to improve it by providing visual feedback to the user when the submit fails. Can I use the messages framework with FormView? if so how?

```
# views.py

class EventImport(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):                                                                       
    template_name = 'polls/event_import.html'                                                                          
    form_class = EventImportForm                                                                                        

    def form_valid(self, form):                                                                                        
        form.foo(self.request)                                                                      
        return super().form_valid(form)  

# forms.py

class EventImportForm(forms.Form):
    url = forms.URLField()

    def foo(self, request):
        logger = logging.getLogger('django')
        try:
            ...
        except:
            trace_back = traceback.format_exc()
            logger.warning('Failed to import. %s', trace_back)
            messages.add_message(request, messages.warning, 'Failed to import. ')
        logger.info('Import complete')
```

error `int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'function'` on `messages.add_message(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`messages.warning` is a function that makes use of the `messages.WARNING` with `messages.add_message`

```
messages.add_message(
    request,
    messages.WARNING, # All upper case,
    'Failed to import.'
)

# and if you want to shorten it with messages.warning

messages.warning(
    request,
    'Failed to import.'
)
```

But what makes me question myself is that how did you managed to get that error and not a syntax error prior for using `import` as a variable?

Comment: I abbreviated the method name. I'll update the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of displaying a warning like this:

```py
messages.add_message(request, messages.warning, 'Failed to import. ')
```

do this:

```py
messages.warning(request, 'Failed to import. ')
```

For More info, Refer to: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/#adding-a-message